# Will the GTX 1060 physically fit in my PC and can I link it to the gpu I already have?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I want to get a new graphics card with a GTX 1060 GPU for my computer.  My only concern is if it will physically fit into my computer.  I bought the PC with an expansion bay to put a new graphics card in later down the road but I'm unsure of the size of these boards and if it will fit in the bay.

I also have a board with a GTX 760 which I'm currently using and I was wondering if there is a way to link these both together or to the motherboard to get even more power or do I have to replace my 760 with the 1060.

**Specs:**
**PC:** ASUS Desktop PC K30AD_M31AD_M51AD Series
**OS:** Windows 10
**Processor:** Intel Core i7
**Ram:** 12GB

Comment: Determine the largest GPU your case will fit, then look at the specifications for the GPU you want, if the GPU you want is smaller then the largest GPU that your case will fit then it will work.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). You could try [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm disagreeing with you here. This is not a hardware recommendation, but question whether it will work or not. I do agree that this is off-topic because it seems to attract opinion based answers rather than fact-based answers, though.

Answer (score 2):

Found the size of it on: http://www.geforce.com/hardware/10series/geforce-gtx-1060

Graphics Card Dimensions:
Height: 4.378"
Length: 9.823"
Width: 2-Slot

You will have to replace the 760 with the 1060 when it comes out. You cannot run 2 different video cards at the same time. The only way to have 2 cards is in SLI and they have to be identical cards.

Comment: A secondary non-heterogenous graphics card can be used for PhysX, ref: [PhysX FAQ](http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_faq.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the PC you posted, it seems like a standard ATX case. I can't say for sure though, because ASUS didn't give that information on their website.

The GTX 1060 will fit in a standard ATX case, as it can be expected to be as big as the 1070/1080. If you want to use both your GPUs for Gaming at the same time, they have to be of the same type and support SLI - in other words, you will have to replace the 760.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, you should be able to put that card in a standard ATX case.

You can't SLI 2 different models of video card, YET. They can be [different manufacturer's](http://www.geforce.com/whats-new/guides/introduction-to-sli-technology-guide#4) and have different clock speeds but they have to be the same model and memory size.

***[These](http://www.overclock.net/t/1568936/is-it-possible-to-sli-a-960-and-a-970-together) posts([second](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/microsoft-directx12-amd-nvidia,28606.html)) mention being able to SLI non-matching GPU models in Win 10, with DX12 but it sounds like it will require the game to also be running DX12 and the game decides how to divide processing

Answer (score 1):

Determining if the card fits is going to be up to you. The size of the card changes slightly with each manufacture and model. For example I found the measurements of a `GTX 1080 by GIGABYTE` that was `9.5"x4.35"`. Where a `GTX 1080 by MSI` measured `10.59" x 4.37"`

As far as your inquiry about being able to link the two cards together to gain more performance? The answer is fuzzy. In the past for SLI to work, the cards had to match to an extent. Not it's reported with DX12 on Windows 10 you can mix and match cards. DX12 is not supposed to be launched until July 29th, 2016 so it's not clear how smoothly this will work once it's released.

If you want to try it out, I'd suggest holding onto your GTX 760 and trying it out a month or so after DX12 is out.